# c# windows form guess the image game

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically, Im creating a project with windows form c# in visual studio. Im trying to make a guess the image game. Ive made two buttons, one randomises the image that is shown and the other is going to display whether they guessed it correctly or not. Im struggling on the second button click as I dont know how to get the number of image from the first button to the second button.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    rInt = r.Next(1, 21);
    string path = @"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Badges/Badges/";
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path + rInt.ToString() + ".png");
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Badges/Badges/";
    if (textBox1.Text = rInt)
    {
        label3.Text = "You Guessed Correctly, Well Done!!";
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = "Incorrect Guess, Try Again!";
    }
}
```

Comment: do the users simply have to type in a number in `textBox1` ?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear as how this game should work.
Do the users have to type in a number in `textBox1` and your click checks this number ?

if so, you can do it like this.
What it does is simply store the random number in the tag property of pictureBox1 so you can acces it from the other click event.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int rInt = r.Next(1, 21);
    string path = @"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Badges/Badges/";
    int i = r.Next();
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path + rInt.ToString() + ".png");

    // store the random number in the pictureBox
    pictureBox1.Tag = rInt;
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == pictureBox1.Tag.ToString())
    {
        label3.Text = "You Guessed Correctly, Well Done!!";
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = "Incorrect Guess, Try Again!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn’t display the message and I don’t know why

Comment: Did you debug it ? Did you get an error ? Can you give some more info please

Comment: Yeah I ran it and it worked but when I went to check the Input, it didn’t display whether it was right or wrong and it didn’t come up with an error message either, it’s as if the button just had nothing in there.

Comment: at the very least it should display "Incorrect Guess, Try again!" Unless there is an error. Please put a breakpoint at the first line and step thru the code

Comment: My computer has literally just ran outta battery, I get home later, I’ll see if it works again later, and try what you suggested, thanks

Comment: When I go to submit the answer, It just doesn't pop up with the correct outcome. It says nothing.

Comment: hows your button 2 set up? I might have set it up wrong?

Comment: The code in my answer is a copy / paste from my testproject. Make sure that the correct event is coupled to the button. When your not sure, put a new button on the form, doubleclick it, and put the code in there

Comment: It worked! I had to recreate the button like you said. Cheers buddy!

Comment: How would I come about doing like a Message box pop up if you get the image correctly guessed showing a different version of the image(It will be in a different folder but with the same numbered names)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a [**field**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Write your `int i;` (or better `int selctedImage;`) above the the first button method with a `private` access modifier. `private int i;`

Your **both** methods will then be able to access this field and use it like a local variable. But remind that this field can be uninitialized at the point of execution of the second method!

***Like This:***

```
private int selectedImage;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    selectedImage = r.Next(1, 21);
    string path = @"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Badges/Badges/";
    // int i = r.Next();
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path + selectedImage.ToString() + ".png");

}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Badges/Badges/";
    if (textBox1.Text == selectedImage.ToString())
    {
        label3.Text = "You Guessed Correctly, Well Done!!";
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = "Incorrect Guess, Try Again!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make rInt a field member of the form. Then you can set it in button1 click and check it in button2 click.

int? randomIndex = null; //f.e.

It would be better if you post the code directly as it would be easyer to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your image number variable outside of the two button-click methods. This will make it accessible to both methods. Like so:

```
int i = 0; // Place it here instead
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assign i here like you did
    i = r.Next();
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // i is usable here now!
}
```

The reason it wasn't accessible in your example is that each method is in a different scope. Variables declared in one scope are "invisible" to another scope. So variables you declare inside MethodA() are invisible to MethodB().